# Batch File: Create Shortcut and Open in Chrome as App

Tags: windows, google-chrome, batch-file, shortcut

I'm trying to create a batch file that creates a shortcut to a web address with an icon and opens Chrome in app mode/fullscreen/kiosk. This works as expected when trying:

```
chrome.exe --app="http://app.mydomain.com"
```

When created from the batch file, the address opens in a new window (or new tab if window is open). Why isn't my shortcut using the --app="" part? 
Create.bat File below:

```
@echo off 
@echo. 
@echo.
@echo.

::Set the application-specific string vars 
SET AppDescription=GRS
SET IconName=logo.ico
SET Shortcut_Name=GRS.url
SET URL_PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --new-window --start-fullscreen --app="http://app.mydomain.com" 

::Set the common string vars 
SET WORKING_PATH=%~dp0
SET ICONDEST=c:\ProgramData\%AppDescription%
SET LinkPath=%userprofile%\Desktop\%Shortcut_Name%

@echo. Copy Icon 
IF EXIST "%ICONDEST%" (GOTO _CopyIcon) 
mkdir "%ICONDEST%"
:_CopyIcon 
copy "%WORKING_PATH%%IconName%" "%ICONDEST%"

echo. 
echo. Create desktop shortcut... 
echo [InternetShortcut] > "%LinkPath%
echo URL=%URL_PATH% >> "%LinkPath%"
echo IDList= >> "%LinkPath%"
echo IconFile=%ICONDEST%\%IconName% >> "%LinkPath%"
echo IconIndex=0 >> "%LinkPath%"
echo HotKey=0 >> "%LinkPath%"
echo. 
echo. 
echo. 
echo. 
echo.You should now have a shortcut to %AppDescription% on your desktop...
echo. 
pause
```

Comment: try  --app=http://192.168.1.10/ not use comma

Answer (score 0):

Because you must use `argrument` to extended: --app=???

Below alls, .BAT file i use to create Shortcut with argruments:

```
@echo off
cd c:\
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > CreateShortcut.vbs
echo sLinkFile = "%userprofile%\Desktop\POS.lnk" >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo oLink.Arguments = "  http://localhost/  --kiosk  --kiosk-printing" >> CreateShortcut.vbs
   var pathe =  "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application";
echo oLink.WorkingDirectory = pathe >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo oLink.Description = "My Application" >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo oLink.IconLocation = "C:\logo.ico" >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo oLink.Save >> CreateShortcut.vbs
cscript CreateShortcut.vbs
del CreateShortcut.vbs
```